# Django ajax error: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I want to implement search with django and ajax.

HTML:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal action-form filter-form" method="get" id="search-form-panel">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" name="product-title" class="form-control" placeholder="products" id="search-text-panel">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success search-btn">search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="manager-list-container">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="basic_list" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                ...

<script>
    let updateProductSearchUrl = '{% url "update-product-search-item" %}';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/product/panel-update-product.js?v={{ SITE_VERSION }}"></script>
```

and in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('it is calling JS part');
$('.search-btn').click(function () {
    submitSearch();
});
$("#search-text-panel").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e && e.keyCode === 13) {
        submitSearch();
    } else if (e) {
        let searchText = $('#search-text-panel').val().trim();
        if (searchText.length > 3)
            submitSearch();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
function submitSearch() {
    let searchText = $('#search-text-panel').val().trim();
    console.log(updateProductSearchUrl);
    $.get({
        url: updateProductSearchUrl,
        data: {'q': searchText},
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {
            if (res) {
                $('#basic_list').find('tbody').empty().append(res.res);
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

ursls.py:

```
path('update-product-search-item/', views.update_product_search_item, name='update-product-search-item'),
path('panel', views.product_panel_view, name='product-panel'),
path('panel/product-type/add', views.product_panel_view_add, name='panel-product-type-add'),
path('panel/product-type/update', views.product_panel_view_update, name='panel-product-type-update'),
path('panel/not-exist', views.product_panel_not_exist, name='panel-product-not-exist'),
path('panel/not-exist/details/<int:product_id>', views.product_panel_not_exist_details, name='panel-product-not-exist-detail'),
path('panel/cargo', views.product_panel_cargo, name='panel-product-cargo'),
path('panel/cargo/create', views.product_panel_create_cargo, name='panel-product-cargo-create'),
```

and in views.py:

```
@staff_only(url_name='panel/product-type/update')
def update_product_search_item(request):
    print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@2')
    print('it is calling this funciton')
    try:
        products = ProductType.objects.first()
        res = render_to_string('product/panel_update_product_type.html',
                            {'products': products}, request=request)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'res': res}), content_type="application/json")
    except Staff.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

by using these codes, when I click on search box it returns :

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8082/admin/login/?next=/admin/update-product-search-item/%3Fq%3Dproducts net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

what is this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check "Network" tab of browser devtools, see where is it redirecting you from and to. And show your urls.py

Comment: it seems it is in a loop of ````http://127.0.0.1:8082/admin/login?next=/admin/update-product-search-item/%3F%26q%3D```` and ````http://127.0.0.1:8082/admin/login/?next=/admin/update-product-search-item/%3F%26q%3D```` and ````http://127.0.0.1:8082/admin/update-product-search-item/?&q=````    @IvanStarostin

Comment: Okay, please show full urlpatterns list

Comment: QUESTION IS EDITED @IvanStarostin

Comment: How do you include/enable admin/auth url patterns/views?